# Text editor with indented word wrapping

Tags: vim, editors, text

I've been using Notepad++ in windows for a while and it has a cool feature for word wrapping so that the wrapped text is indented. That is the start of the sentence starts at column 1, but wrapped text starts at column 3 (or 4 or whatever). I believe it is called Indent style for word wrapping. Very convenient when you have long lines. I played with vim, but didn't have success getting similar behavior.

Does any text editor in Linux support this type of word wrapping?

Answer (score 7):

In vim you can do something like:

```
:set showbreak=..
```

Comment: Wow- excellent. This also works. ":set showbreak=\ \ "

Comment: The first has the advantage that vim will display those characters in another color, which helps to distinguish those breaks from real newlines.

Answer (score 4):

There's still a famous and often-requested [break indent patch](https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent) in the queue for Vim; this will improve on the existing `'showbreak'` by properly indenting the wrapped line.

**Addendum**: The patch has been accepted upstream, so since version 7.4.338 all you have to do is `:set breakindent` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com) also has this feature, and the width and type of indent are configurable.